# Zooming in WP application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a large image on my WP application page. It its barely visible so I would like to zoom this image. What do I have to change in my app to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`var scale = new ScaleTransform { ScaleX = 1.5, ScaleY = 1.5 };
 imgPhoto.RenderTransform = scale;`

[ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx)